# Duplicate http post in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I have a problem with $http post in Angularjs. Any one can help on how to avoid  avoid duplicated requests...
Here is my code in controller

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute', 'pascalprecht.translate']);
myApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $translate, $location, $rootScope, $http, $filter, $interval) {
var myInit = function () {
            $http.post("API_V1/api.asmx/fetchALLRate", { data: {} })
                  .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                   this.objRate = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                   //do something...
            });
        };
angular.element(document).ready(myInit);
```

And here is image for
[duplicate request error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fEyy.png)

Thank you in advance.. hope that anyone could help me out...btw, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can you show the regarding html where you define `mainController` and `ng-app` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for `angular.element(document).ready(myInit);`. Change it to `myInit();`

Comment: still duplicate bro :(

Comment: thats weird. Are you sure you aren't calling myInit twice. Just to be sure, add a console.log in the myInit function to check if its getting called twice.

Comment: Yes bro, im not calling myInit twice or declare controller twice. I dont known why that error occured.

Comment: Here is my HTML code bro <html ng-app="myApp">
<head id="head" runat="server">
    //some javascript
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainController"></body>

Comment: Thanks alot , because you forcus on my problem Tarun . I handle my problem by the way i use "ng-init cho <body> tag". Thanks again !